# Run chained method before anything in constructor?

Tags: javascript

I have this simple class:

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.init();
    return this;
  }

  init() {
    this.onInit();
  }

  onInit(callback) {
    this.onInit = () => callback();
    return this;
  }
}

new Foo().onInit(() => console.log('baz'));
```

It's obviously flawed, because it will call `init` before the `onInit` method is able to define the `onInit` property/callback.

How can I make this work without change the interface?

Comment: If you define "init" as "when the constructor is being executed", then setting the callback as a chained event to said constructor (which by definition executes *after* the constructor) is simply contradictory and there's no logical way to resolve that.

Comment: I see your point, the fact is that my library is `new Something().onCreate().onUpdate()`, and it makes sense because it creates the instance, and then you set what you want to do after the instance is created (and when it's updated). So, "grammatically", it makes sense and I would like to find a way to keep it..

Comment: *Grammatically* it'd make sense if we could write *"Computer, make a cup of tea"*, but realistically we have to bow to the rules of the programming language… ;)

Comment: Yes absolutely, that's why I asked on SO, because I really want to make it work in this way but I know it's problematic...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I make this work without change the interface?

You can't, the interface is inherently flawed. That's really the answer to your question.

---

Continuing, though, with "what can I do instead":

If you need to have a callback called during initialization, you need to pass it to the constructor, not separately to the `onInit` method.

```
class Foo {
  constructor(callback) {
    this.onInit = () => {
        callback();  // Call the callback
        return this; // Chaining seemed important in your code, so...
    };
    // Note: Constructors don't return anything
  }
}

new Foo(() => console.log('baz'));
```

---

In a comment you've said:

> I see your point, the fact is that my library is `new Something().onCreate().onUpdate()`

It sounds like you might want to adopt the [*builder* pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) instead:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(callbacks) {
        // ...use the callbacks here...
    }
    // ...
}
Foo.Builder = class {
    constructor() {
        this.callbacks = {};
    }
    onCreate(callback) {
        this.callbacks.onCreate = callback;
    }
    onUpdate(callback) {
        this.callbacks.onUpdate = callback;
    }
    // ...
    build() {
        // Validity checks here, do we have all necessary callbacks?
        // Then:
        return new Foo(this.callbacks);
    }
};

let f = new Foo.Builder().onCreate(() => { /*...*/}).onUpdate(() => { /*... */}).build();
```

...although to be fair, a lot of the advantages (though not all) of the builder pattern can be realized in JavaScript by just passing an object into `constructor` directly and doing your validation there, e.g.:

```
let f = new Foo({
   onCreate: () => { /*...*/},
   onUpdate: () => { /*...*/}
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to move everything in the constructor options, it's useless to fight against the language :/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `onInit` is supposed to be some sort of hook to be called synchronously whenever an object is instantiated, you can't solve this on the instance level.

You can make `onInit` a static function, like so:

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    // whatever
    Foo.onInit();
  }

  static onInit() {} // empty default
}

Foo.onInit = () => console.log('baz'); // Override default with your own function
const f = new Foo();
const f2 = new Foo();
```

Comment: Thanks, but doing so I need to split the command in multiple lines, don't you have an idea to keep it as a chained commands list? Hacks are welcome I guess..

Comment: By the time you have a basis for your command, it's too late, so no. Not possible I'm afraid.